# Reading another device's file structure via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to read another mobile device's file structure if my device is connected to that device via Bluetooth?

It's not how to send files, but to see the file structure of another device in Android devices.

The mobile is Android platform and the other device can be any Bluetooth device.

So from my mobile device I want to read Bluetooth device's file structure.

Comment: Do you mean 'file structure' as the content of file system on the device? You want to see or browse list of files and folders on another device from your Android device?

Comment: yup content of the file system.
And if possible I wantt to browse

Comment: Bluetooth FTP server in older phones support browsing, but the folder structure is virtual, but it is possible for the phone to implement FTP server to mimic the actual file system folder structure in that case the FTP client can browse the content. Since this is insecure most of the modern day phones doesn't support FTP server.